# Porting of Plural string from Localizable.strings to Localizable.stringsdict with %@ input formatter in the middle of stirng

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, localizable.strings, plural

In `Localizable.strings`, I have below plural strings with one and other

> "User added %@ posts.##{one}" = "User added a post.";
>
> "User added %@ posts.##{other}" = "User added %@ posts.";

I wish to remove it from Localizable.strings and add it to Localizable.stringsdict.

I have done this before for the basic strings with the input format (%d) at the start of string. But, I have never user Localizable.stringsdict for strings having input format in middle of the string

**Could anyone help me with exporting the above string in below format?**

```
<key>Fill_Here</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>Fill_Here</string>
    <key>Fill_Here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>Fill_Here</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>Fill_Here</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>Fill_Here</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, by modifying dictionary as below

```
<key>User added %@ posts.</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@posts@</string>
    <key>posts</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>d</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>User added %d post.</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>User added %d posts.</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Using %@ input format crashes the application in this case. So I modified it to use %d instead.